# Transformations Filter

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, ravendb

I have the following Map / Transform

```
public class PositionSearch : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Employer>
{
    public PositionSearch()
    {
        Map = employers => 
            from employer in employers
            from position in employer.Positions
            select new
            {
               EmployerName = employer.Name,
               SearchSkills = position.RequiredSkills
                                      .Select(x => x.Skill)
            };

        TransformResults = (database, results) => 
            from result in results
            from position in result.Positions
            select new
            {
                EmployerId = result.Id,
                EmployerName = result.Name,
                PositionId = position.Id,
                PositionTitle = position.Title,
                RequiredSkills = position.RequiredSkills
                                    .Select(x => new { x.Skill, x.Proficiency })
            };

        // Any field you are going to use .Search() on should be analyzed.
        Index("SearchSkills", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

I have an employer object with two positions, each with a single skill, "NH" and "MVC"

When I execute the following query I'm getting two position results returned, when I expected one.
Can anyone tell me why this is behaving this way? I've got a feeling it's something to do with a join i'm performing, but I'm not sure.

```
using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
{
     var results = session.Query<PositionSearchResultModel, PositionSearch>()
                    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
                        .Search(x => x.SearchSkills, "NH")
                    .OfType<PositionSearchResultModel>().ToList();

      Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count());
}
```

I'm wanting to use transform so that I can access the Temp-Index-Score meta data for ordering, I've been unable to access the meta data without a transform so far.

Comment: I have removed tags from the title of the question. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indexing the `Employer` document. The search found a document that contained the skill in question, and then you asked to transform the *document*.

The way you had it [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14835172/634824) is projecting from the index, which is the only way you are going to get the specific position found as part of your results.

I really think you would be happier with `Position` as it's own document...

```
public class Employer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Position
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployerId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SkillProficiency> RequiredSkills { get; set; }
}
```

This may seem more relational in thinking, but it works just fine in RavenDB, and it will be much easier to query than what you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks very much! - In your opinion, would it make sense for me to have documents that aren't aggregate roots, and take this approach. Or stick with projecting from the index? - Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I would argue that in your case, `Position` is actually an aggregate.  Evidenced by your need to project them individually.  Consider the case of `Order` and `OrderLines` - you would never put `OrderLines` in their own document.  If you searched by an ordered item, you would still return the entire `Order`.  But you aren't asking for `Employer`s that have a `Position`, you are asking for the actual `Position`s.

Comment: I think I just felt a few lightbulbs turn on. Thanks very much for all your help! - Hopefully I won't need to post yet another question any time soon!